# How do I protect a buffer from using multiple threads?

Tags: c++, algorithm, locking, mutex, semaphore

There is a flaw in my implementation and I cannot figure out. I have a worker thread that inconsistently calls the callback to write to a buffer named "m_bufferLatest" The buffer needs to be copied over and it takes some time to finish copying in the main thread. So I need to protect "m_bufferLatest". So in the main thread when I call ContinuousCapture() I set a flag called "m_skipFrame" so that the call back ill not write to m_bufferLatest.

But when I run my program m_bufferLatest is null depending on how fast the worker thread runs.

Can someone please help me what is wrong with my program ?

```
bool HandleEofCallbackCont() 
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_EofMutex);

    if (!m_skipFrame) {
        //here update m_bufferCont
        if (!m_camera->SaveLatestFrameToQueue())
        {
            printf("get latest frame failed.. \n");
        }

    }

        m_EofFlag = true;
    }
    m_EofCond.notify_one();

    return true;
}

bool ContinuousCapture(Settings settings)
{
    //wait for the condition variable otherwise timeout
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_EofMutex);
    {
        if (!m_EofFlag)
        {
            m_EofCond.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(10), [&]() {
                return (m_EofFlag);
            });
        }

        m_skipFrame = true;

        int size = m_camera->m_bufferBytes / sizeof(uns16);

        //transfer from data
        if (!TransferData(settings, (uns16*)m_camera->m_bufferLatest, size, m_Frame))
        {
            printf("transfer data failed");
            return false;
        }

        m_skipFrame = false;
        m_EofFlag = false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is what I'm trying to do. 
[image]

Comment: One thing which immediately sticks out is that m_skipframe is set when mutex is locked, but checked outside of mutex.

Comment: Another thing - if Transfer failed - flag is still true so no more writes will be done. Also you are waiting for EofCond under mutex lock. What do you expect other thread will do in this case? I would use mutex only to protect buffer and make flags atomic...

Comment: @SergeyA I moved m_skipFrame to be inside the mutex, but it still doesn't work. I get the invalid access memory. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to synchronize between two threads, it is very important to use the synchronization primitives.  Also to decrease the time when the system is locked by mutexes.  Although mutexes allow guaranteed state between different threads, they tend the performance towards single threaded performance.

```
m_SkipFrame = true;
```

Is visible on one thread, but some form of `interthread-happens-before` needs to occur to ensure that the other thread is not working.

```
std::atomic<> is a good mechanism, for testing state between the threads.
```

Assuming you only have one reader, and one writer.  The following scheme would work the easiest.

1. Create a class to encapsulate the buffer.  This class would be used to pass information from writer to reader.
2. Use a pointer to this in your interaction class, but have it stored in a std::atomic
3. Dispose of the finished pointer in either the reader or the writer.

Assuming a class holding the buffer.

```
class BufferHolder {
};
```

Then within an Interthread class

```
class Interthread {
    std::atomic<BufferHolder*> m_Exchange;
}
```

Then a writer would be ....

```
void Interthread::Writer( BufferHolder * pNewBuffer ) {
   BufferHolder * oldBuffer = m_Exchange.exchange( pNewBuffer );
   delete oldBuffer; // may be nullptr, but that is ok.
   // if the oldBuffer wasn't used, it was sort of wasted.
}

BufferHolder * Interthread::Reader() {
   BufferHolder * pNewBuffer = m_Exchange.exchange( nullptr );
   return pNewBuffer;
}
```

You may need to have a queue, or some mechanism for storing a fixed number of buffers.